# How can i pass the value of an input field inside React Navigation to another page?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an Input field that is rendered inside the headerTitle of React Navigation. I want to get the value that is being typed at the search/index page. How can i do it?

```
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar } from '../components/SearchBar';

export default function Layout() {
  return <Stack>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="(tabs)"
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="search/index"
      options={{
        headerTitle: () => (
          <SearchBar />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Stack>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Screen` component in the page instead to configure the header bar.

```
function Search() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Stack.Screen
...
          // https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component
          headerTitle: props => <SearchBar onSubmit={(query) => ...} />,
        }}
      />
...
    </View>
  );
}
```

See [Configure header bar](https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/stack/#configure-header-bar) for details.